# textarea didn't convert into tiny MCE while called in javascript

Tags: tinymce

i have problem while called text area that should be convert into tiny MCE from insert.php into manage.php. please help.thx

here my code

insert.php

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({....});   
    </SCRIPT>

    <?php
        echo '<TD>';
        echo '<textarea id=texta></textarea>';
        echo '</TD>';
    ?>
```

manage.php

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add").click(function() {
            $.post("insert.php",{},function(data) {
                   $("#content").html(data);
            });
            });
        });
    </SCRIPT>
```

when i click #add its load insert.php but the textarea inside insert.php won't change into tiny MCE editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that tinymce.init gets executed after the phph is fully loaded (you may use `$(document).ready` for this).